# Removing Duplicates In MySql

Tags: mysql

I have inherited a database that has a "Duplicate problem".

when I run:

**SELECT myFIELD, COUNT(*) c FROM myTABLE GROUP BY myFIELD HAVING c > 1;**

I get ~600 records that are duplicated

None or tripled or any other multiple

I wish to kill off one of the records, leaving me with no duplicates.

What does the query look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like this ... you should repete the query  depending how many time the same row is duplicated ..

```
delete from my_table 
where (myFIELD, id) in  
(select a.myFIELD, max(a.id) 
FROM myTABLE as a  GROUP BY a.myFIELD HAVING count(*) > 1)
```

otherwise you can use

```
delete from my_table 
where (myFIELD, id) not in 
(select a.myFIELD, min(a.id) 
FROM myTABLE as a GROUP BY a.myFIELD )
```

this should delete all the duplicated rows in a shot

If there problem  with table name

```
delete from my_table 
where (myFIELD, id) in  (select field, id from 
(select a.myFIELD as field, max(a.id) as  id
FROM myTABLE as a  GROUP BY a.myFIELD HAVING count(*) > 1) as t)
```

Comment: Tried: delete from my_table 
where (myFIELD, id) in  
(select myFIELD, max(id) 
FROM myTABLE GROUP BY myFIELD HAVING c > 1)   But got error:  Unknown column 'c' in 'having clause'

Comment: Not Quite there yet! :  delete from my_table 
where (myFIELD, id) in  
(select myFIELD, max(id) 
FROM myTABLE GROUP BY myFIELD HAVING count(*) > 1)  ThrowsYou can't specify target table 'myTAble' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Which of the 3 query do you used ?